# Index on child records based on critera from parent record?

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema, relational-database

I am designing a schema that contains two tables in parent-child relationship. One query that I am concerned about is that the child records will be queried repeatedly based values in two fields in parent records. The use-case involves selecting child records where a field in the parent record is equal to 1 and another field is greater than zero. ***For this use-case, no information is needed from the parent records.***

A month's work of data contains ~500,000 parent records and ~1,500,000 child records. The use-case in question will probably return 99% of the child records.

Is there any way to setup an index on the child table that is based on the critera fields from the parent table? I've considered denormalizing a bit and adding a couple of criteria fields to the child records, but am hesistant to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it sounds like an [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would get you what you want.

You would be able to only include columns in the display of the view from your child table, while joining to the parent table for the column = 1 check you require.

A rough example of a solution may look like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwChildTableRestrictedByParentValues
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   SELECT ct.col1, ct.col2, ct.etc
   FROM dbo.ChildTable AS ct
   INNER JOIN dbo.ParentTable AS pt ON ct.ParentId = pt.ParentId
   WHERE pt.OneField = 1
      AND pt.AnotherField > 0;

GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_vwChildTableRestrictedByParentValues
ON dbo.vwChildTableRestrictedByParentValues
(
   Col1 ASC
   , Col2 ASC
   , etc ASC
)
```

Where the index includes the columns that you want to index on for the child table.

If you do not have Enterprise Edition, you will have to write your query against the view.  If you do have Enterprise, the query can be written against the tables, but still use the index you have created here.